# Display Time in select query - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I got an existing Mysql table with one of the columns as `time int(10)`

The field has many records like

```
1455307434
1455307760
```

Is it a date time, encrypted.

What should be the select Query, so it should display an actual date.

Comment: Your “encryption” is likely no encryption at all, but those values are simply unix timestamps. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1455307760);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(mycolumn)
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: You are welcome :) can you please accept the answer.

Comment: yes it says to accept i will have to wait for 2 mins